# Content administer page

Tags: drupal-6

Is it possible on the content page to publish pages with checkbox, instead of the update options on the top, is there a module, or something to be configurated?

My main goal would be to change in the edit of a page the cck fields settings by taxomony but it doesn't look possible. So instead I'm making different pages to point on a same url.

So every week I can't change a specific url content by publishing and unpublishing pages. But with the update options you have to select one then choose publish and then update, after that choose another page by clicking his checkbox, choose unpublish and then update, is there an easier way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the manager module

http://drupal.org/project/manager

Here is a screenshot of what it does:
[image]

Comment: It's very interesting but you still have to do what i've writing in my post, like select by checkbox some page to publish and others to unpublish. It would be fun to have a check box on the side of the pages with publish and unpublihs option instead of the drop down list on the top. But thank you I've installed the module ands there's alot of very cool options, maybe i have to go deeper in it.

Comment: I don't think there is a content management system that currently does that. This manager is as good as it gets

Comment: Can I actually change the field options on a page edit with taxonomy terms, like week 1, you have some fields, week 2 you have other ones with Ajax so when saving the page , it updates a specify ulr content, that is ultimately what i'm looking for?